# USB thumb drive appears in Manager, but not in Windows

Tags: windows-7

I have a cheapo 32 GB thumb drive I'm trying to use to move some data between machines. When I plug it in I can see it add the drivers, but that's it, it doesn't mount.

Opening Device Manager, I can see it as Disk 1 in the Disk Management. It says "No Media". Is this dead, or just needs to be set up somehow?

Answer (score 0):

- It could be dead on arrival. In such case nothing can be done.
- The driver corresponding to it is not loaded (very unlikely). If it came with some driver software, make sure to install it first.
- Keep the device connected and check "Windows Updates". If something new pops up, install it.
- It could be that the storage is formatted with file system that is not Windows friendly. eg: ext2,3,4. This is also unlikely.
- When it showed as a disk in "Disk Management", try formatting it with diskpart.

Open command prompt as administrator, and enter `diskpart`. Now enter the commands.

```
list disk
select disk 1
clean
create partition primary
format fs=fat32 quick
```

Assuming your disk is disk1. You may omit the quick option for marking any bad blocks as bad blocks. Some of the commands might show errors if the disk is dead.